# Links to visited titles of questions in new search results need more contrast

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, search

For items that are not simply tag searches, the contrast between the colors of a visited link and a non-visited link are *very* low, making it difficult for me to determine what pages I've visited.

For example, on Stack Overflow, this is what I see:

[image: New search results on Stack Overflow]

It's even *worse* on Meta Stack Overflow:

[image: New search results on Meta Stack Overflow]

It's also on all of the beta sites:

[image: New search results on beta site]

I appreciate subtlety in design, but this is one of those areas where it's a major hindrance.

I'm currently viewing this in Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m on Windows XP SP 3.

Comment: Isnt this browser dependent ? I see different degree of contrasts on Chrome/Windows, IE/Windows and Chromium/Ubuntu

Comment: @AshRj Updated with browser version.

Comment: It was more of a question :) Is it supposed to be browser-dependent or is it a bug ?

Comment: @AshRj I would think it's not supposed to be browser dependent, and I didn't look at the CSS (I'm not digging through that).  It should be consistent across browsers, and this has been the styling for the search since the new one came out, which is why I think it's a feature request.  I think there's more styling that needs to be done overall, because the results are a wall of text, but that's a separate issue.